# AncestryDNA is changing again? What's going on? (July 2020 edition)

Tags: autosomal-dna, ancestry.com

AncestryDNA is changing the way they match users, and which matches will be shown to you. **Matches that share 6 to 7.9 cM will be eliminated.** In addition, since AncestryDNA rounds up segments from 7.5 to 7.9999 to 8, as I understand it, some matches that appear to be 8 cm will also be eliminated. This self-answered question is intended to collect links to articles and blog posts explaining what's happening.

Roberta Estes says in her [18 July update](https://dna-explained.com/2020/07/16/ancestry-to-remove-dna-matches-soon-preservation-strategies-with-detailed-instructions/):

> ONLY segments to be salvaged will be ones in groups, with notes or matches whom you have messaged. Ancestry has confirmed that matches
> without these things, meaning matches in ThruLines or that you have
> placed in your tree will NOT BE PRESERVED unless they are grouped,
> have notes or you’ve messaged.
>
> The determining factor is total cM, not smallest cM. So total cM
> between 6 and 7.9999, which rounds up to 8 will be removed. Multiple 6
> cM segments where the total is 12 will be fine, for example. Again,
> it’s the total cMs, so no math needed.

The users who will be hit hardest by the change are people using small-segment matches to tease out data about distant cousins.

If you want to preserve your data, please read the blogosphere and learn how to add your matches to groups or make notes against them before the changeover ("before the beginning of August", according to Chris Paton).

My opinion: It might be a good idea to add the people you've messaged with to a group, as a safeguard, due to the fragility of the Ancestry messaging system.

Resources from AncestryDNA:

- The new [AncestryDNA Matching White Paper](https://www.ancestrycdn.com/support/us/2020/07/2020whitepaper.pdf)
- [Ancestry Blog:category DNA](https://blogs.ancestry.com/ancestry/category/dna/)

Posts from bloggers will appear in my answer in reverse chronological order.  I invite community members who are using AncestryDNA to post their own answers about saving data as well. If you want to add to the list of blog posts, please put the link in the appropriate place in the calendar, so the newest posts appear at the top.

Comment: I would remove the paragraph about the user's being hardest hit are those doing African-American research. That is a conclusion that Roberta posted based on her own personal experience, but is one that is very controversial and disagreed on by many knowledgable genetic genealogists.

Comment: @lkessler I'd be open to an edit that makes it more clear that this is Roberta's opinion. I understand both sides here. Ancestry is too cheap to devote the server space and processing cycles to serve what they see as a small subset of users who want this data, yet they are obstructive of efforts by third parties to let users capture that data.  Some genealogists have said "well you should have had notes on the matches you want to keep already" which ignores any future customers who want to see this data.

Comment: Jan, each company provides a set of tools and capabilities that they feel they can offer. Ancestry provides many features that others don't. Just because you expect certain functionality in no way means Ancestry is obligated to provide it.

Comment: @lkessler, while I'd agree that Ancestry has no obligation to offer tools or capabilities that they consider unprofitable. I certainly expect, that having offered a tool or service (that they previously determined to be economically justified), they may actually have an obligation to annual subscribers to provide continuity to at least the termination of the subscription term!

Comment: @Jan. Ancestry has determined themselves that the tool at 6 and 7 cM is inaccurate. They are constantly improving their tools and adding new ones. They are under no obligation to keep tools they find to be inaccurate, but moreso would be expected to remove said tools. Net result is improvement for the user.

Comment: @lkessler Reminder: I am not using AncestryDNA.  I only want to provide information about how to save this data for the users who are currently taking advantage of it. Ancestry's going to do it's thing.  What needs to be in the question that isn't already?  If you want to argue for the sake of arguing about how much information can be squeezed out of these matches, we can do that in chat.

Comment: @Jan - I'll bring something up in the meta about this question when I get some time.

Comment: @Jan - I've added into Meta: https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3494/should-we-include-documentation-type-questions/3495

Answer (score 2):

This answer collects articles and posts from the community about the changes at AncestryDNA, with articles in reverse chronological order.

- 25 July 2020  Dana Leeds: [Using Very Small Segments: A Success Story](https://www.danaleeds.com/using-very-small-segments/)
- 23 July 2020  LostCousins newsletter (Peter Calver): [Ancestry DNA changes – what you need to do now!](https://www.lostcousins.com/newsletters2/latejul20news.htm#Ancestry&gsc.tab=0)
- 19 July 2020 Louis Kessler's Behold Blog (Louis Kessler): [Proof or Hint](https://www.beholdgenealogy.com/blog/?p=3515)
- 19 July 2020 DNA Explained (Roberta Estes): [Plea to Ancestry – Rethink Match Purge Due to Deleterious Effect on African American Genealogists](https://dna-explained.com/2020/07/19/plea-to-ancestry-rethink-match-purge-due-to-deleterious-effect-on-african-american-genealogists/)
- 19 July 2020 The Legal Genealogist (Judy G. Russell): [Chilling with AncestryDNA](https://www.legalgenealogist.com/2020/07/19/chilling-with-ancestrydna/)
- updated 18 July 2020 (was 16 July) DNA Explained (Roberta Estes): [Ancestry to Remove DNA Matches Soon: Preservation Strategies with Detailed Instructions](https://dna-explained.com/2020/07/16/ancestry-to-remove-dna-matches-soon-preservation-strategies-with-detailed-instructions/)
- 17 July 2020 Dana Leeds: [Notice: Ancestry’s Update Will Remove Some DNA Matches](https://www.danaleeds.com/ancestrys-update/)
- 17 July 2020 The DNA Geek (Dr. Leah Larkin): [AncestryDNA’s 2020 Matching White Paper](https://thednageek.com/ancestrydnas-2020-matching-white-paper/)
- 17 July 2020 The Genetic Genealogist (Blaine Bettinger): [Losing Distant Matches at AncestryDNA](https://thegeneticgenealogist.com/2020/07/17/losing-distant-matches-at-ancestrydna/)
- 17 July 2020 The Scottish GENES Blog (Chris Paton): [Changes to AncestryDNA matches in early August](https://scottishgenes.blogspot.com/2020/07/changes-to-ancestrydna-matches-in-early.html)
- 15 July 2020 Your DNA Guide (Diahan Southard): [AncestryDNA Updates Coming: What To Do Next](https://www.yourdnaguide.com/ydgblog/2020/7/15/ancestrydna-shared-matches-updates)
- 14 July 2020 Cruwys News (Debbie Kennett): [Some updates to AncestryDNA's matching system and a database update](https://cruwys.blogspot.com/2020/07/some-updates-to-ancestrydnas-matching.html)
- 14 July 2020 Lara's Genealogy (Lara Diamond): [Longest Segment Coming on AncestryDNA!](https://larasgenealogy.blogspot.com/2020/07/longest-segment-coming-on-ancestrydna.html)
- 14 July 2020 LostCousins newsletter (Peter Calver): [Thousands of DNA matches will disappear soon URGENT ACTION REQUIRED](https://www.lostcousins.com/newsletters2/jul20news.htm#Disappearing)

Peter says:

> The aim is to remove false matches – matches that occur by chance, or
> because of statistical anomalies. But whilst improving the quality of
> matches is important, it's inevitable that many valid matches will be
> discarded. Indeed matches could disappear even if Common Ancestors
> have been identified.
>
> However, if you’re quick there's a possible solution - I've been
> advised that matches of under 8cM won't disappear should any one of
> the following apply:
>
> 1. ```
>    You've added them to a group (using one the 32 user-definable coloured circles)
>    ```
> 2. ```
>    You've entered something in the Notes field
>    ```
> 3. ```
>    You've sent a message to the other member
>    ```
>
> I suggest you give priority to those where common ancestors have been
> identified.

Further Reading:

- 4 Mar 2020 LostCousins newsletter (Peter Calver): [Masterclass: How to make the most of your DNA test](https://www.lostcousins.com/newsletters2/mar20news.htm#DNAMasterclass)

Comment: When I search for a Ancestry member (member search) the display (currently) will tell me my DNA match level with that person. After Ancestry makes their changes, will that information still appear if the match level is 6 thru 7.9?

Comment: @BobE Presumably that information would disappear.  Ancestry has said they'll save the  match information if you've made notes, messaged the person, or added the match to a group, but it's possible that the match level information may only be available through the match list.

Comment: If fear that you may be correct, however just talked to a telephone rep who said that a 6-7.9 match would still be displayed on the person's profile, regardless! What doesn't make sense is that if I message someone with a 6.5 cM, then later go to their userprofile it would/would not display their match level. Having sent a message is a condition that would have to be met before a 6-7.9 level is allowed to be displayed on their user profile???

Answer (score 1):

As a supplement to Jan's very comprehensive answer, I would add information as to the timing of the announced purge. From Ancestry's FAQs on the issue:
[image: Ancestry.com on 7-30-2020]